# How to test cron @reboot entry?

Tags: cron, crontab, cronjob

How can I test if @reboot is working without the need of reboot the machine? 
Is there anyway to force @reboot to entry to run?

Thank you.

Comment: Copy it and schedule it to run at a time shortly in the future? Remember to undo the copy after its run.

Comment: That said, depending on the job, even if you can trigger it without a reboot, it may not be equivalent because the system could be in a different state when its launched @reboot.

Answer (score 4):

crond is checking if the file /var/run/crond.reboot exists. If it exists, cron skips @reboot jobs

```
sudo rm /var/run/crond.reboot 
sudo service cron restart
```